# Simple ActionBarSherlock error with Fragments

Tags: java, android

When writing this code I am having a constant error where it says "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Fragment_1 to Fragment" on the three lines like this "Fragment Fragment1 = new Fragment_1();". I believe this is the problem that is also causing my fragments to not appear when the code is run because the code doesn't know what corresponds to the Listener.

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionbar.setTitle("TabApp");

    ActionBar.Tab Frag1Tab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Tab 1");
    ActionBar.Tab Frag2Tab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Tab 2");
    ActionBar.Tab Frag3Tab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Tab 3");

    Fragment Fragment1 = new Fragment_1();
    Fragment Fragment2 = new Fragment_2();
    Fragment Fragment3 = new Fragment_3();

    Frag1Tab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(Fragment1));
    Frag2Tab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(Fragment2));
    Frag3Tab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(Fragment3));

    actionbar.addTab(Frag1Tab);
    actionbar.addTab(Frag2Tab);
    actionbar.addTab(Frag3Tab);



}

class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    public Fragment fragment;

    public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment){
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab,    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

}

Here is the Fragment_1 class:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Fragment_1 extends Fragment{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is likely in your Fragment_1 class.  It may not inherit form the correct Fragment parent class.

Comment: @Tarun It is just a class inflating a layout XML I have created for it. I can add it to the post if you want.

Comment: yes, do post the code..

Comment: @ScottW That has fixed the problem. Thanks for your time guys. I was just an idiot and forgot about the other files.

Comment: Inherit fragment_1 from SherlockFragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is Fragment_1 inheriting from android.support.v4.app.Fragment(or SherlockFragment)? Or does it inherit from android.app.Fragment? It should be android.support.v4.app.Fragment